# regex on sql script

Tags: regex, notepad++, sql-scripts

I need to perform a search and replace operation on hundreds of SQL script files. The idea is to transform this:

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/* comments xxxx */
ALTER PROCEDURE ....
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
```

Into this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ....
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
```

To do this I would use *Notepad++*. I want to remove anything before `ALTER PROCEDURE`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following with `. matches newline`:

```
Find what:    USE\s+\[[^\]]*?\].*?(ALTER\s+PROCEDURE.*?\bEND\b)
Replace with: $1
```

`\[[^\]]*?\]` will make sure you will match any characters from `[` up to `]` after `USE`.

**EDIT**: If you plan to just remove *everything* from the beginning to the last occurrence of `ALTER`, you may use `.+(?=ALTER)` regex in the *Find what* field, and replace with nothing (empty string).

Settings:

[image]

Comment: my target is  to remove anything before "ALTER". maybe something simpler?

Comment: Everything? Then `.*?(?=ALTER)`. And replace with nothing.

Comment: This find the occurrence, it tells me that one replacement has been made but it actually does not remove anything

Comment: I have tried this `.+(?=ALTER)` now, and it matches up to the last `ALTER`. Is that waht you need? You can use `.+?(?=ALTER)` to match just blocks between `ALTER`s. I think you need something like `USE .+?(?=\bALTER\b.*\bEND\b)` and replace with empty string.

Comment: Aaah it works! Sorry, silly me. I did not select the "matches newline" option.